# Coffeescript - 'this' is always replaced by '_this' in fat arrow callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript, this, jquery-callback

I'm wondering is possible somehow to prevent `this` keyword to be transformed into `_this` inside fat arrow callback (`=>`)?

For example:

```
class someClass

  someMethod: ->
    $(document).on 'click', '.myclass', (e) =>
      # doing things with right context this, it's ok
      @anotherMethod()
      @oneMoreMethod()

      # but here I need jQuery ``this`` pointing to element
      $el = $ this # this is transformed into ``_this`` :(
```

Maybe I missed some option or operator?

**UPDATE**
I know about the trick like `self = this`, but I thought CS has something more elegant..

Comment: Try using `$(e.target)`

Comment: in my specific case ``e.target`` is not a solution, I need to use ``this`` to get the specific element with attribute I'm selecting and not its children.

Comment: An odd trick to get this to work is replace `this` with `<backtick><space>this<backtick>` and it uses the normal `this` as expected. The space is required between the first backtick and this. See it [here](http://coffeescript.org/#try:class%20someClass%0A%0A%20%20someMethod%3A%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%24(document).on%20'click'%2C%20'.myclass'%2C%20(e)%20%3D%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%23%20doing%20things%20with%20right%20context%20this%2C%20it's%20ok%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%40anotherMethod()%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%40oneMoreMethod()%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%24el%20%3D%20%24%20%60%20this%60)

Comment: Nobody owes you a comment with a downvote. Somebody thinks your question is "unclear or not useful", or lacks research.  Probably because your question makes no sense. You're asking how to prevent the single, solitary behavior that `=>` is expressly designed to give you. If you don't want that behavior, use `->`.

Comment: @vcsjones That sort of chicanery will almost certainly fail at some point when the CoffeeScript compiler is updated. Depending on bugs and quirks is a really bad idea, doubly so when there are sensible solutions.

Comment: @muistooshort Agreed, but the space is just to work around an [existing bug](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffeescript/issues/2009) already. The CS compiler shouldn't be changing `this` when inside backticks, that's the point of them.

Comment: @vcsjones Fair enough. I tend to think of the existence of backticks in CoffeeScript to be a bug all by itself, it should be harder than that to shot your own foot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's the whole purpose of `=>`.

Use `$(e.currentTarget)` to get a handle to the element that would have been `this`. This is not the same as `$(e.target)` which you have already rejected.

And no, CoffeeScript **can't** have anything more elegant way to handle this. You can only have one context for a function. Bound functions aren't unique to CoffeeScript, they're a feature of JavaScript, and the solution is for the calling code to provide another way of accessing the element, which jQuery does with `e.target` and `e.currentTarget`.

Comment: Not sure I agree with the last paragraph. I *thought* older versions of CoffeeScript behaved such that skinny vs. fat arrows only affected how `@` behaved, not the literal keyword `this`, as in `@` would capture the `this` before the function's context, and `this` would just always be left alone as `this`.

Answer (score 4):

The purpose of the `=>` fat arrow as opposed to the skinny arrow `->` is to prevent changing the context of `this`. You have multiple options here. One option is to store a reference to `this` inside a variable, such as the following.

```
self = @
method: -> @ is self # true

self = @
method: => @ is self # false


class someClass

  someMethod: ->
    self = @
    $(document).on 'click', '.myclass', (e) ->
        # self (by default) refers to your class
        # @ refers to the jquery object (context)
```

Comment: yeah, I know that JavaScript trick.. I though Coffee has something more elegant to handle it..