# Rails jQuery 'post' problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

In my project I have a button with approximately such code:

```
<a class="start btn" href=start_process_path(@process.id) id="start">
  <i fa class='play'></i>
</a>
```

and have a jquery event listener for it:

```
$('.start').click((function(_this) {
    return function(e) {
      var params;
      params = $('form', _this.previewJq).serializeArray();
      $.post(e.target.href, params, function(json) {
        if (json.error) {
          return alert(json.error);
        }
      });
      return false;
    };
  })(this));
```

In my `routes` file I have such lines:

```
resources :processes do
  patch 'start',  on: :member
end
```

The problem is that sometimes when I click that button I reacts with nothing. If I open console in Chrome or look in logs, I can see that it throws 404 error saying that I'm trying to send post request to the page that has this button.
When I open sources in Chrome browser and but a breakpoint on a line with a post request, it usually works fine. But once I've managed to caught situation when it sad that `e.tagret.href` has `undefined` value (or smth like this).
What can be the reason for it to be like this? Why jquery can't get href parameter correctly?

Thanx in advance!

Comment: There is a missing quote in "$('.start)". Is that a typo?

Comment: @HithamS.AlQadheeb Yes, surely it's a typo! Fixed. Thanx. That was not a reason for problem:)

Comment: You need to check that element has href values or not or try to check undefined also

Comment: @RohitKumarChoudhary How can it not to have 'href' parameter, while it's hard-written in html-code?

Comment: Try replacing `e.target` with `this`. If `.start` has child elements, `event.target` may be one of its children.

Comment: @Ngoral as you said e.target.href has undefined. You need to check the element has an anchor tag with href value. You have not posted your html code. Please post that too.

Comment: @Vanitas you were almost right: the problem was I had an icon inside, and clicking on this icon caused this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was clicking on `i` element caused `e.target` having it, not a button inside.
Since I'm using coffeescript, comment of @Vanitas and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24540478/coffeescript-this-is-always-replaced-by-this-in-fat-arrow-callback) answer helped me.

I just needed to replace `e.target.href` with `e.currentTarget.href`.